# Tabbed-Menu where tabs Change Color?

Tags: menu, navigation

I need a tabbed-menu template where the tabbed menu for the present page **changes color**.  If possible, it should play nicely with browser that don't have JavaScript enabled.

Other then the tabs, I prefer a simple blank page without complicated CSS.

Comment: What is your question? Are you familiar with Javascript and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is this. Each page has it's own class for the body, e.g.

> <body class="tab3">

Each tab should have its own id, tab1, tab2, tab3 etc.

Then put a line like this in your CSS:

> .tab1 #tab1, .tab2 #tab2, .tab3 #tab3 { color: *selected colour* }

You'll have to specify which element of the tab you want to be coloured, I've just put in "color".

Then when the body tab has the class tab3, tab3 will be the selected colour.